# Ubuntu 18.04.01 - apt-get not able to download packages or not working... wget works for the same - please help

Tags: apt, 18.04, wget

`apt` update fails with the following errors messages:

```
$ apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But `wget` works for the same url:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
--2018-09-26 12:12:17--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.149, 91.189.88.161, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 242048 (236K)
Saving to: ‘InRelease’

InRelease                                   100%[==========================================================================================>] 236.38K  1.42MB/s    in 0.2s

2018-09-26 12:12:17 (1.42 MB/s) - ‘InRelease’ saved [242048/242048]
```

Comment: Are you on a corporate or school network with a proxy? Has apt failed for more than 12 hours?

Comment: i am on corporate network without any proxy.... its a new build of ubuntu 18.04.01  and its getting failed.

Comment: Are you *really really sure* there's no proxy? What you have described seems like a classic incorrect apt-proxy setting.

Comment: @user535733  i have even disabled the proxy in the /etc/environment file... i donot see nay proxy configuration under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ as well... **env | grep -i proxy**
 https_proxy=
http_proxy=
ftp_proxy=   .   Below is the source list i am using... do i need to use any different repos..... it is connecting fine with wget command **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main

Comment: @Vinod Kuma did you get any solution for this ?